# Struct serialization in C with binn

Tags: c, sockets, serialization, tcp

I'm actually trying to send a struct over TCP socket, i tried to serialized the struct with [binn](https://github.com/liteserver/binn), but on their github their showing how to serialize then send the serialized struct, the fact is i don't know how to read the serialized struct in the connected computer. Can someone explain me ? Thanks for your answer.

Here is the thread handler code who send struct to another computer :

```
void *node_handler(void *node_info)
{
 t_thread   *info;
 binn       *obj;

 info = (t_thread *)node_info;
 obj = binn_object();
 binn_object_set_int32(obj, "id", info->identifier);
 binn_object_set_int32(obj, "socket", info->thread_socket);
 binn_object_set_str(obj, "info", "trying to send string");
 send(info->thread_socket, binn_ptr(obj), binn_size(obj), 0);
 return (NULL);
}
```

Comment: Your would probably receive it like any other chunk of data. For a fixed size know to sender and receiver loop around `recv()` until all data had been received. For a chunk of varying size send the size before the chunk using a fixed format known to sender and receiver (for example a 32 bit unsigned integer converted to network byte order).

Comment: Do you mean "I don't know how to read data from a socket" or "I don't know how to de-serialize the serialized data after reading it from the socket?"

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory if you look at the [examples](https://github.com/liteserver/binn/blob/master/examples/reading.c), specs and docs on their repo. What have you tried? Also, you're not freeing the `binn` object you create here. Before returning, call `binn_free(obj)`. Also, returning `NULL` just for the sake of a `void *` return is silly. don't return anything, and change your function to `void node_handler(void *)` instead. If the problem is knowing how to read from a socket, show us what you've tried, and what you've googled so far

Comment: Here is how im trying to recv :

        recv(sock, binn_ptr(obj), binn_size(obj), 0);

Comment: Should i send the size of the obj before , then read this size and open_binn() after ?

Comment: Finally i found how it work , thanks for your answers!